# Is the 1 year IDP really necessary for any country if you have the 3 year IDP?

Tags: legal, international-travel, driving-licenses

My country (Czechia) issues both 1 year and 3 year versions of the [International Driving Permit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Driving_Permit). The 1 year version is supposedly issued under the [1949 Convention on Road Traffic](https://treaties.un.org/doc/Publication/MTDSG/Volume%20I/Chapter%20XI/xi-b-1.en.pdf), while the 3 year version is issued under the [1968 Convention on Road Traffic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vienna_Convention_on_Road_Traffic). Notably the United States is party to the 1949 convention, but not the 1968 convention.

But is the 1 year version really necessary for any country that accepts IDPs? Can I just go ahead and get the 3 year version instead? I'm planning to travel to South East Asian countries, which usually require IDPs at police checks.

Comment: What is an IDP?

Comment: International Driving Permit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a bit of Googling it seems that **yes**, some countries really do care about seeing a 1949 IDP.

- **Japan**. [Europcar states the following](https://www.europcar.com/EBE/module/render/http:/www.europcar.com/Specific-Terms-popup?link=267C5529-3272-1652-7C32-5E302F787F4C:ContentPopupTerms&locale=en_US) about their Japanese rentals:

  > International Driving permit based on "Geneva Convention of Road Traffic 1949" should be presented at the time of pick up. It is the only International driving permit acceptable in order to drive in Japan.
  >   No other exception is allowed, especially note the following international permit or license is INVALID and UNACCEPTABLE in Japan.
  >
  > International Driving Permit based on Vienna Convention 1968

Comment: I'm making this a community wiki to allow people to add other countries.

Comment: Note that some countries (CH, D, FR, BE, MC or TW) are allowed to translate their DLs in Japan (those countries are parties to 1949 GC but don't issue 1949 IDPs)